# How can I get screen position of a UI element?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the global position of a UI element.

I've tried so many different ways to get the position but none of them seems to work. The problem comes with the anchors, as i'm moving them and not the UI element position itself (for resolution purposes), the position of the UI showing in the inspector is always 0,0,0. I also tried to get the anchoredPosition and also the Corners to make some calculations but it still not working, I always get (0,0,0) or some incoherent numbers.

```py
 Vector3 pointToTravel = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(objectRectTransform.anchoredPosition);
```

This 'pointToTravel' variable should hold the screen position in pixels of the ui element.

Answer (score 9):

[`anchoredPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) is the

> position of the pivot of this RectTransform **relative to the anchor reference point.**

---

Since [`RectTransform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html) inherits from `Transform` you can simply use

```
Vector3 pointToTravel = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(objectRectTransform.position);
```

in order to get the absolute world position.

The `position` you see in the in the Inspector is always the

- `localPosition` for `Transform` - relative to the parent GameObject.

  or
- `anchoredPosition` for `RectTransform` depending on the anchor settings - relative to the anchor reference point.

---

**However** in the case your Canvas is a `Screen Space - Overlay` all the contained UI (or better `RectTransform`s) already uses the screenspace coordinates in **pixels** so the `WorldToScreenPoint` is unnecessary or better said returns incorrect values.

So in that case you could instead simply use

```
Vector3 pointToTravel = objectRectTransform.position;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get any information you could need about the dimensions and position of a UI Element from its RectTransform, I wrote this little utility function to convert a `RectTransform` to a Screen Space - `Rect`(For Canvas mode Screen Space - Camera).

```
public static Rect RectTransformToScreenSpace(RectTransform transform, Camera cam, bool cutDecimals = false)
{
    var worldCorners = new Vector3[4];
    var screenCorners = new Vector3[4];

    transform.GetWorldCorners(worldCorners);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        screenCorners[i] = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(worldCorners[i]);
        if (cutDecimals)
        {
            screenCorners[i].x = (int)screenCorners[i].x;
            screenCorners[i].y = (int)screenCorners[i].y;
        }
    }

    return new Rect(screenCorners[0].x,
                    screenCorners[0].y,
                    screenCorners[2].x - screenCorners[0].x,
                    screenCorners[2].y - screenCorners[0].y);
}
```

From this rect you can easily get all the information that the `RectTransform` does not give you that easily, such as Screen-Space-position and non-anchored size.