# Drag and drop detection on a UI rect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, drag-and-drop, rect

found [a script on Github](https://github.com/Bunny83/UnityWindowsFileDrag-Drop) which implements a drag and drop feature in Unity. There, I adapted the code "ImageExample.cs" to my project. It happens that I can't make the drop point detection system work with my UI. The drop point is composed of a empty UI object (only a rect transform and the adapted code), with the actual UI visual elements as it's children.

Already google a bunch of stuff trying to figure out what's the problem, without success. Tested some [RectTransformUtility's](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.html) methods, checked answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869568/how-can-i-get-screen-position-of-a-ui-element) or [this one](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1013011/convert-recttransform-rect-to-screen-space.html)(top 2 answers) and etc..

The following method is my adapted version to receive and load the image:

```
protected void LoadImage()
{
    if (dropInfo == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Information is null!!");
        return;
    }
    Debug.LogError("Rect pos is " + dropRect.position);
    Debug.LogError("Rect transform pos is "+rectTransform.position);
    Debug.LogError("aInfo is " + dropInfo.pos);
    if (dropRect.Contains(dropInfo.pos))
    {
        var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dropInfo.file);
        receivedImage = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        receivedImage.LoadImage(data);
        onTextureUpdate(receivedImage);
        onDropInfoUpdate(dropInfo.file);
    }
}
```

Where:

"aInfo" it's assigned as the author's example, just with a single texture instead of array.

"rectTransform" represents the empty UI container, meaning the valid area to receive images.

"dropRect" stands for the "rect" variable inside of "rectTransform"

If I drop the image in the correct zone, nothing happens and this values are presented:

[image]

After some testing, I could find a place where the image is received by the application, but the position is totally wrong (top left corner of the window), this values are show in this case:

[image]

Anyway, it shouldn't be something hard, but my grap of UI x screen coordinates and stuff like that is bad apparently. Hopefully somebody will have an answer to my dobut.

Comment: The question leaves so much unsaid. But there is phrase you used that makes ne wonder if you’ve actually used an “empty UI object” as a drop target? If so, that’s likely the issue. You need to have (in general) a “component” for the graphics raycaster to be able to hit. Try placing an Image with a dummy texture (an all white rectangle for instance, but on second thought, I’m not even sure you even need to assign an texture there,  I’m not in front of computer sorry) and set the alpha to 0, therefore hiding it. Let’s see if that helps the raycast detection.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-GraphicRaycaster.html) Says that it looks for all the “Graphics” on a canvas, which lends credit to my previous suggestion.

Comment: I've tried to explain everything in succinct way. I'm not sure the mentioned scripts works with a raycast (if it's possible to this without it anyway) , didn't take a closer look on it's internal parts. I just took the example and tried to fit it to my needs. About the empty object, it literally only has a Rect Transform and the adapted script "ImageExample.cs" provided by the author. Considering the drag and drop itself is working, the issue appears to be with some coordinate calculus, indicating that the image should be received only within the mentioned rect limits...

Comment: “Try placing an Image with a dummy texture (an all white rectangle for instance … and set the alpha to 0”. Add an `Image` to the empty UI object, and set it’s alpha to 0.

Comment: Tested with both Image and RawImage (standard settings, only assigned a white Texture/Sprite on each case), nothing changed, the valid area still stuck on the top left corner of the window instead of the correct UI gameobject.

Comment: That’s a shame. I’ve built a drag-and-drop system for the old uGUI, and then another one recently using the new UIToolkit. I recall that the older uGUI needed an Image as a target for the internal Graphics Raycaster.